# SQL Get table count, group by number range

Tags: sql, count, where-clause, having

I have a news table with a number of rows.  My page populates the rows in groups of 12 by loading separate PHP pages for each set.

Is there SQL statement that will allow me to query the table, get the row count, and isolate based on a determined number range.  For instance, if I only want rows 13-24.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have something like `row number` field in your database?  If you don't, then row numbers can be determined only in conjunction with certain **order**.  What is your definition of `row 13`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the database. Assuming you have mysql, use LIMIT.

In the example below 13 is the start row and from there it will give 12 rows.

```
select * 
from  tbl
order by  field1, field2
limit 13 , 12
```